# How do you use a dictionary's `get` method with higher-order-functions like map with mypy and typings?

Tags: python, python-3.x, mypy

I have the following rather simple code snippet using `map` with a dictionary's `get` method as the map function:

```
OverlapDict = Dict[str, Set[str]]

oMap: OverlapDict = openOverlapMap(sys.argv[1])

oMapKeys: List[str] = list(oMap.keys())[0:nOverlapKeys]
oMapVals: Iterable[Set[str]] = map(oMap.get, oMapKeys)  # type: ignore
```

If I remove the `# type: ignore`, I get the following error:

```
 error: Argument 1 to "map" has incompatible type overloaded function; expected "Callable[[str], Set[str]]"
```

Is this a known issue, or is there a workaround that doesn't require using the type ignore (that is also hopefully not overly cumbersome or performance-reducing)? I suppose it is possible there is some other error in my code, but it seems to be working as intended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `dict.get()` return `None` as default value if key does not exist, you need to use `Optional`:

```
oMapVals: Iterable[Optional[Set[str]]] = map(oMap.get, oMapKeys)
```

Comment: That makes perfect sense; somehow I thought I'd seen a use elsewhere that indicated it wasn't correctly ascribing `Optional`. I was able to use `filter` to change the line to: `oMapVals: Iterable[Set[str]] = filter(None, map(oMap.get, oMapKeys))`

Answer (score 0):

you're probably better to use `map.__getitem__` instead of `map.get` here.  Since you've already ensured that the keys are present you don't need to do additional filtering afterwards to convince mypy that `.get(...)` will always return a value:

```py
oMapKeys: List[str] = list(oMap.keys())[0:nOverlapKeys]
oMapVals: Iterable[Set[str]] = map(oMap.__getitem__, oMapKeys)
```

`__getitem__` is the magic method name for the `[...]` operator

Comment: mypy does a few things I'm not used to in other type systems, like tracking such assurances behind the scenes. In fact, the only one I knew of before this is checking of Optionals, like `if foo is not None:`. I will try this out soon.